# python write(string) saves normally but sometimes it saves as a list of characters

Tags: python, string

I've the following simple function which saves a string to a file:

```
def writeFile(path, data):
    with open(path, mode = 'wt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("".join(data))
        file.close()
```

I tried to use file.write(data) and then I replaced data with "".join(data) but it doesn't change anything. Most of the time, the string is saved normally but sometimes, it is saved as a list of characters, meaning that each character of the string is separated by \n and I don't understand why.

Comment: The code you posted won't add newlines, that must be happening in the caller.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example of a condition where this happens.

Comment: Your code is a bit awkward.  If `data` is a string, then `"".join(data)` will just break it up into characters, and then join it back together into the original string.  Your original data must have the newlines.

Comment: You don't need to use `file.close`. The context manager automatically closes the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things going on here:

First of all, `"".join(data)` doesn't change the string - it breaks up `data` into characters, and then just join it back together to the original string. Therefore the newlines that are causing your issue - are in the original string.

Secondly, as you are using the context manager, there is no need to use `file.close` - the context manager automatically closes the file.

Comment: This is the string sent to writeFile(): "Last hour:       0.00 NM (0.00 kt)
Last 6 hours:  Not enough data
Last 12 hours: Not enough data
Last 24 hours: Not enough data"

Comment: add `print("\n" in data)` at the start of the `with open` section. If you get `True` that means that data contains at least one newline. To remove newlines from the string, you can use `data = data.rstrip()`

Comment: Yes, this string contains exactly 3 newlines (some text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text", isn't it possible to save a string with newlines inside as a block of text because I need the newlines inside this string?

Comment: You can split the string by newlines using `data.splitlines()`. This will return a list of the lines in `data`, breaking at line boundaries. Line breaks are not included in the resulting list. You can later add the newline character to each line when you need the string to include it.

Comment: You can actually add the parameter `keepends=True` to keep the newlines, so `data = data.splitlines(keepends=True)` will give you a list of the lines with the newlines included at the end of each line.

Comment: OK thx, I'll try but since this issue appears from time to time, I'll have to try many times in real situations

Comment: You can troubleshoot this by giving `data` different strings and then check the results of your implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241300/discussion-between-eyal-golan-and-swiftiti).

Answer (score 0):

thx for your support, I made a new function converting my list into a string

```
def listToString(aList):
    retStr = lf = ""
    for element in aList:
        retStr = f"{retStr}{lf}{element}"
        lf = "\n"
    return retStr

def writeFile(path, data):
    with open(path, mode = 'wt', encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(data)

data = ["12","34","45","..."]
writeFile("data.txt", listToString(data))
```

Comment: If my answer answered your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks